# jai jpeg2000 encoder not found

Tags: java, jai, jpeg2000

I'm using JAI and looking to read and write jpeg2000 files on Mac OS X (Linux soon thereafter) and am having trouble loading the codec.  It seems that there are a couple of different projects available, yet, many seem half-baked (not started, not finished, only the source is available, etc).

I'm not married to JAI, just what I started with.

The codecs I currently have are:

```
com.sun.media.jai.codecimpl.PNMCodec@36d251a3
com.sun.media.jai.codecimpl.JPEGCodec@29edc073
com.sun.media.jai.codecimpl.FPXCodec@37f5d386
com.sun.media.jai.codecimpl.GIFCodec@6c121f1d
com.sun.media.jai.codecimpl.TIFFCodec@19b8e059
com.sun.media.jai.codecimpl.WBMPCodec@38910040
com.sun.media.jai.codecimpl.PNGCodec@37a786c3
com.sun.media.jai.codecimpl.BMPCodec@578088c0
```

I'm using these Jars:
    jai-core-1.1.3-alpha.jar
    jai_codec-1.1.3-alpha.jar
    jai_imageio-1.1-alpha.jar

and this is available to me:

```
com.sun.media.imageio.plugins.jpeg2000
```

But when I try to encode to jpeg2000, I get:
"Encode The specified format has no associated registered ImageCodec."

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Tom

Answer (score 1):

Try using Java Advanced Imaging Image I/O Tools (aka JAI I/O Tools), provides more I/O codecs like JPEG2000. It's a "plugin" for JAI providing more image I/O codecs, requires JAI installed.

http://download.java.net/media/jai-imageio/builds/release/1.1/